# Crash follows removal of bold face from \mathcal{} in running fancyhdr header

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, fancyhdr, books, mathcal

While my bold calligraphic letter is fine in the chapter title or table of contents, it's out of place when it is the only bold character on a running header. My attempts to remove this have caused a compilation error. I've got a  long document that has a few chapters with \mathcal{} in the header. I've found that after a successful first compilation, the second fails. (Other attempts to correct the first occurrence, the table of contents suffers for every subsequent chapter by having erroneous content appended to the legitimate table of contents entry.)  Clearly there's something I'm missing here, suggestions welcome. MWE for the compilation error on 2nd run follows:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,svgnames]{book}      
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
 \usepackage{cite,lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}  
 \usepackage{amsbsy,amsmath}  
%  \usepackage{hyperref} %replace LaTeX in pdf file thumbnails with something more palatable, but this features in another broken case
\usepackage[inner=25mm,outer=15mm,bottom=25mm,top=20mm]{geometry} 
   \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
    \markboth{CHAPTER \thechapter{}: \MakeUppercase{#1}}{}%
  \else
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}%
\fi}


\begin{document}
\fancyhf{}  
  \setlength{\headheight}{30pt}  
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}   


\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
 \fancyhead[RO]{\makebox[0cm][l]{\makebox[0cm][r]{\thepage}}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\makebox[0cm][r]{\makebox[0cm][l]{\thepage}}}
 \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} 


\frontmatter
 \tableofcontents  
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\mainmatter

% chapters
 \chapter{first chapter} 
\lipsum

\chapter{second chapter}
\lipsum

\chapter{First pesky calligraphic character in chapter  $\boldsymbol{\mathcal M}$ }

%% comment this out to allow compilation to complete and see the unwanted bold characters in running headers
   \chapter{First pesky calligraphic character in chapter  $\boldsymbol{\mathcal N}$ \chaptermark{First pesky calligraphic character ${\mathcal N}$}}  \chaptermark{First pesky caligraphic character ${\mathcal N}$}

\lipsum[4] 

\chapter{Third pesky calligraphic character in chapter  $\boldsymbol{\mathcal O}$}

\newpage  
\lipsum[4] 

%  \chapter{Second pesky calligraphic character in chapter \texorpdfstring{$\boldsymbol{\mathcal N}$}{N}\chaptermark{First pesky calligraphic character ${\mathcal N}$}}  \chaptermark{First pesky caligraphic character ${\mathcal N}$}

% Add the bibliography to the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}  
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the usage of `\chaptermark` inside of `\chapter` really needed? `\protect\chaptermark` seems to work, however

Comment: @ChristianHupfer maybe the answer to your question is no, but that's what I found on the net looking for a solution. Removing the first \chaptermark and applying your suggestion to the second seems to solve the MWE problem. I'll see if it also works on my original problem.